# jQuery function that keeps a field active

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I created this little function jQuery that when we select an option it returns the value:

[image]

But when I click on another option above, the value disappears and I need to go back in the select field and select another option to appear again

[image]

how can i keep this effect on click without it disappearing like that? Thanks for reading this far!

My code that handles this field:

```
if ($('.wc-pao-addon-distribuicao select').val() == 0 || $('.wc-pao-addon-tamanho-da-empresa select').val() == 0 || $('select#formato').val() == 0) {
    $("#product-addons-total").hide();

  } else {
    $("#product-addons-total").show();

  }
});
```

Comment: The question is hard to understand.  "*I need to go back in the select field and select another option*" - do you mean the "Distribuicao" or "Tamanho da ..." selects?  If yes, does your code somehow reset those selects when the main HD/4K option is chosen/changed? I think we need to see more of your code to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is a problem with your logic. Your current logic defines that out of 3 fields if one of them is 0, you hide the total and when all are not 0 then only you show the total.

so whenever you choose all the values and they are not 0, the total is showing. but when you change an option, one of the values is reset to 0 and in this case, your logic definition for hide statement becomes true.

So, you need to understand and correct your logic.

What I am thinking here is that the logic should be that out of 3 fields if one of them is not 0 then show the total. so we'll define this condition by this code:

```
if (
    $('.wc-pao-addon-distribuicao select').val() != 0 ||
    $('.wc-pao-addon-tamanho-da-empresa select').val() != 0 ||
    $('select#formato').val() != 0
) {
    $('#product-addons-total').show();
} else {
    $('#product-addons-total').hide();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I understood the point you made, but the problem is when I click on the element above "4K" or Vice versa, the field of this value disappears in the same way with this logic that you showed

Comment: It hard to identify what is happening when you change the option, but you can inspect element and keep it open and change the options and notice the changes in input value and debug this issue and then correct your logic.

Comment: Thanks for your time and teaching, I will try to apply now